# Crack RSA with imaginary algorithm

Tags: rsa

I was given a cryptography question during an interview the other day and I couldn't come up with a valid answer. Imagine you are given an efficient algorithm which for a given RSA public key (n,e) is able to decrypt 1% of the messages encrypted with that key. 1% means that the algorithm will deterministically decrypt 1% of all possible ciphertexts on the first call, and will never decrypt the other 99% of all possible ciphertexts with any number of invocations. Figure out an algorithm that uses this one and can decrypt any message.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you add a description of RSA encryption to the question? IIRC it is just $m\mapsto m^e$? Then you can multiply by $2^e$ repeatedly to get encryptions of $m$, $2m$, $\ldots$, and eventually one will be decrypted. Say $2^nm$. Then you multiply this by $1/2^n$ and you are done. (Generally inverting without knowing the factorization of $n$ is hard, but with 2 it's easy: $n$ is odd so $2^{-1} = (n+1)/2$.)

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra Seeing as how it seems like a puzzler my guess is that it's textbook RSA, but yes, simon, it'd be helpful if you could clarify that.

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra Finding multiplicative inverses is always easy, Euclid came up with a working algorithm over two millenia ago. What is hard without the factorization is finding multiplicative *orders*.

Comment: It is not evident that the algorithm in the first [comment](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20787/555#comment49408_20787) succeeds. In fact, _if_ we had $2^{k\cdot e}\bmod N=1$ for some $k<100$, _then_ the algorithm would fail its goal. $\;$ The canonical answer to this question uses random numbers, rather than successive powers of two, in order to avoid that issue.

Comment: @Thomas Oops! That's what I get for posting late at night!